# IF, ELSE statement for sql query

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

How to write a SQL query where I have a table called ACC_REQUEST?

There is a column in the table called REQUEST_STATUS with the values of 'pending', 'withdrawn', and 'completed

If the request status value = 'pending then select approver_name from ACC_APPROVAL, else select request status

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE

Like:

CASE x
WHEN bah THEN FOO
END CASE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN ACC_REQUEST.REQUEST_STATUS = 'pending' THEN ACC_APPROVAL.APPROVER_NAME
        ELSE ACC_REQUEST.REQUEST_STATUS
    END as [put the name you wish for output column here, no square brackets]
FROM ACC_REQUEST
INNER JOIN ACC_APPROVAL ON [I'm assuming some kind of join condition here]
```

Comment: better answer then mine ;)